# Elasticsearch Query Between Two Servers

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new with elasticsearch. I have two elasticsearch servers:

`http://1.20.30.43:9200/`

and

`http://10.30.65.98:9200/`.

In first server i have 100k data and second server i have 100k+1 to 200k data.
I want to search some keywords on both servers in one request. But I have no idea how I can setup two servers in one request.
When cluster name is same

I have no clue which config file I have to change.

Comment: yes javanna clustername is same on both servers

Comment: are both the servers on the same IP subnets?

Comment: Yes both server has same subnets

Comment: Then as I told you in the previous answer you don't have to configure anything. Just send a search request. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: but Sir I am sending request but its not returning real answer i thing i have missing something in configuration file

Comment: Are you using routing in your indexes? Also yo might want to share your elasticsearch configuration file to see exactly how you set up the cluster

Answer (score 0):

we have required these steps

> 1-Put same name o f cluster on both server in elasticsearch.yml file

and then

> 2-Comment these two lines in elasticsearch.yml file

```
> # discovery.ec2.groups: your group
> # discovery.ec2.any_group: false
```

> 3-If you are using ec2 servers then make accessble on both server

```
4-Restart your both servers
```